# Unable to scale Redis cluster to more than 90 nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am using AWS Elasticache with 30 shards and 3 replicas each in EU Frankfurt region. I have a total of 90 nodes in the cluster. While trying to scale beyond this cluster configuration, I am constantly getting the following error

```
Number of nodes in a redis cluster can not be more than 90.(Service: AmazonElastiCache; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: uniqueRequestID; Proxy: null)
```

How can I autoscale my cluster to more than 90 nodes in this case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS Elasticache now supports 500 Nodes Per Cluster. So, your cluster can easily scale to more than 90 nodes. However, for increasing the cluster size to more than 90 nodes, you would need to raise request for a service limit increase for **“nodes per cluster per instance type”** using the **AWS Support Center**.

More information - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/08/amazon-elasticache-redis-supports-500-nodes-per-cluster/

Answer (score 1):

As per the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/quota-limits.html), there is a default quota of 90 nodes per cluster per instance type.

You can request a quota increase using the  https://console.aws.amazon.com/servicequotas/home page from your account. This should be approved by AWS for you to be able to use more than 90 nodes.